# How can i use i tag as input tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace input with `i` tag: it's original code

```
<a class="card-footer text-white clearfix small z-1" href="#">
    <span class="float-left">
        <form id="myform" action='model/excel.php' method='post'>
            <input type='submit' name='export_excel' value='Export To Excel' class='btn btn-default btn-sm'/>
        </form>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Would simply embedding the input tag within an <li> achieve what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: what?? what's your goal here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a Font Awesome Excel icon in your button for submission. In that case, I would switch to a button and place the icon inside of it:

```html
<button type="submit" name="export_excel" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-excel-o"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: I will show what I want: use <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-excel-o"> like input or submit to post function to another page

Comment: @Ala'Sawaftha I revised my answer after your clarification.

Comment: I want use <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-excel-o"> as a input contain name and class

Comment: You cannot use `<i>` as `<input>`. They serve completely different purposes. The browser does not recognize `<i>` as a form control. `<i>` is for italicizing text, but Font Awesome and other icon systems use it for displaying their icons. If you want to use an icon as a submit button, I recommend the solution I provided in my answer above.